# Checking if String is a proper date and insert it into database

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I store in database value of `date`.

I display the current date in format:

```
textBoxTradeDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I want insert this date into database. How to check if it is proper value? I don't want use Regular Expression and I need to save this `textBoxTradeDate.Text` in database. Also, the user must be able to change this date, so I can't store `DateTime.Now` and only display date part.

I don't want use `Calendar` tool.

Comment: DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out date); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Tried this, inputString has no `time` part.

Comment: shouldnt be a problem, whats the error you are getting? is it when you try and write to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse()`.

But you should ensure that you specify the expected date format if there is the possiblity of a problem.

```
string datestr = "2001-01-01";
DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParse(datestr, out date)) {
    //write date to db
} else {
    //throw an error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `TryParseExact`, so that you can specify the date format:

```
DateTime tradeDate;
bool ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  textBoxTradeDate.Text,
  "yyyy-MM-dd",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  DateTimeStyles.None,
  out tradeDate
);
if (ok) {
  // correct date, so you can put it in the database
} else {
  // incorrect format, so tell the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> so I cant store DateTime.Now and only display date part.

[SQL Server's `date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) with mapped [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type of .NET Framework. That's why you should insert your datetime value *directly* `date` typed column and this column saves **only** date part of it.

Since you always passing your formatted `DateTime.Now` to `textBoxTradeDate.Text` property, you can just pass this `DateTime.Now` value directly your parameterized insert query.

If you wanna check your `textBoxTradeDate.Text` is a valid `DateTime`, there are `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.TryParse`, `DateTime.ParseExact` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods which they are exactly what this for.

```
string s = textBoxTradeDate.Text;
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // You have a valid datetime.
}
```